# Why do MCU compilers for chips like AVR or ESP (used widely by Arduino) keep all strings in SRAM heap by default?

Tags: c, arduino, compiler-construction, avr-gcc, arduino-esp32

There is a common technique used in Arduino world, where you can use PROGMEM macros in order to keep strings and other similar data in flash memory instead of SRAM to keep lower RAM usage, while sacrificing some performance - https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/utilities/progmem/

Basically, instead of storing these in SRAM, there is just some reference to a FLASH address where the string is stored and loaded from on the fly, in order to save RAM.

But I can't understand why do MCU compilers put all strings including local strings from functions into heap memory and keep them there all the time in the first place. Also I don't understand how compiler can "store anything in RAM instead of flash" - RAM is volatile, so compiler can hardly "store" anything in there as it's cleared on every reset. These strings still must be present in program image stored on FLASH, so why does it copy them from FLASH to RAM on each launch of the MCU? I was thinking that maybe whole program image must be loaded into RAM for execution, but then that doesn't make sense as these chips use harvard architecture and program is executed from FLASH already (and most of these chips have much bigger FLASH than RAM anyway, so whole image would never fit into RAM).

While I understand how to use workarounds that prevent this behaviour, I can't understand why this behaviour exists in the first place. Can someone shed some light on it? Why are all strings loaded into HEAP on start of the program by default? Is that for performance reasons?

Comment: Are you defining your strings as `const`?

Comment: Is there a problem here that is within scope of what Stackoverflow can address?  Maybe you should address, or or make suggestion to the Arduino design forums?  Other than C being used when coding for Arduino, there is nothing about solving a C problem here.

Comment: Only static read-only data can live in flash, any other data _needs_ to be in RAM.

Comment: I believe this is some Harvard architecture thing. It wants to provide a means for fast access to strings without copying them first, because of the limits of the core. But I haven't really used AVR so I'll refrain from answering.

Comment: My guess: strings are considered initialized data, like all other initialized variables. So, at program startup, they're copied from flash to working memory along with everything else. It's just doing what we told it, after all! :-)  Use `const` and `PROGMEM` to put constants (of all types) in flash.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question and topic can be better addressed on the [Arduino Stack Exchange](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @ryyker, the question has nothing to do with arduino. it is about avr/esp toolchain and we can only guess why they designed it that way so it is opinion based

Comment: @Juraj - _"nothing to do with arduino"_...   tags suggest otherwise, but its moot.  Either way, question was off-topic.

Comment: @ryyker: That question is completely fine, IMO, and it's a question that's legitimate and many starters are coming up with it.  It's a GCC design decision, and there are exact reasons behind it. Just the fact that some other place might be better suited won't render it off-topic here, no? Pretty reach end every question about GCC would be better suited in mailing lists `gcc-help@gcc.gnu.org` or `gcc@gcc.gnu.org`, but just that fact does not render them off-topic here?

Comment: @emacsdrivesmenuts -  I do not disagree that this is a fine question, just off-topic for this forum.  It would be better posted to forums that focus on AVR, ESP, et. Al.

Comment: @ryyker: But it's not a question about the hardware, it's about compilers (which Arduino happens to use) in conjunction with specific hardware and programming language.  The question and answer will touch all of these fields, for example tag `avr-gcc` would be compoletely fine for this question, and as far as I know, such user-space questions about `avr-gcc` are not off-topic here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The AVR architecture is different from many other common architectures in that the the code and data exist in completely different memory spaces (though the program memory can be accessed as data, as shown in `PROGMEM` documentation page to which you linked). This is one type of modified Harvard architecture.

Most other architectures that you're likely to use present themselves to the user as having code and data exist in the same memory space. While this is often also done with a modified Harvard architecture, they present themselves to the user as a von Neumann architecture, having a unified code and data memory space.

---

On AVR, to make initialized global or `static` data available to use as any other in-memory data, part of the program startup code copies the initialization data from program memory into RAM. This is generally done to program segments with names like `.data` or `.rodata`, depending on whether or not the variables in question are `const`.

Note that, contrary to what you say in your question, this data is not copied to the heap, it's stored in some portion of RAM chosen during program linking.

Using `PROGMEM` and the associated functions, you can directly access the data stored in the flash memory of the AVR device. This constant data is placed in a segment that won't be copied to RAM on startup, like `.progmem.data`, and so doesn't have space in RAM reserved for it.

---

The case with the Xtensa architecture, used by the ESP8266 and some members of the ESP32 family, is completely different. Contrary to what you state in your question, I don't believe that `static` or global objects which are `const` are copied into RAM by default, only those which can be modified (the `.data` segment would be copied as initialization to RAM, while the `.rodata` segment would not be).

Comment: the question is "why?", so off-topic

Comment: I wouldn't say it's completely off-topic, while it doesn't fully explain the logic and reasoning why the compiler is placing this data into segments that are automatically loaded into RAM during load of program (instead of loading them into RAM on-demand as needed), it still gives lots of useful explanation about how these architectures work.